# Is it possible to use both a certificate and UserName credential type with a service? C#

Tags: c#

I am working on a project that makes requests to an API (which I think is WCF). The API requires an X509 certificate as a credential to be able to make requests. After referencing the service for the client and trying to make some requests, I was told that my requests were also missing a UserName header credential in order to authenticate with the API. Is it possible to use both types of credentials in a request and if so would anyone know how to set it up? Sorry if this post is poorly made, this is my first post on this website.

Edit: The username header that I need is at the SOAP message level. A header in the actual SOAP xml request.

This is my program code (with personal info taken out):

```
using System;
using System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates;
using EFM_User_Service_Test.EfmUserService;

namespace EFM_User_Service_Test
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            X509Certificate2 cert = new X509Certificate2("path to pfx file", "password for file");
            EfmUserServiceClient client = new EfmUserServiceClient();
            client.ClientCredentials.ClientCertificate.Certificate = cert;
            client.ClientCredentials.UserName.UserName = "test@email.com";
            client.ClientCredentials.UserName.Password = "test password";
            client.Open();

            AuthenticateRequestType req = new AuthenticateRequestType();
            req.Email = "test@email.com";
            req.Password = "test password";

            AuthenticateResponseType response = client.AuthenticateUser(req);
            string user_id = "";

            if (response.Error != null && response.Error.ErrorCode != "0")
            {
                Console.WriteLine(response.Error.ErrorCode);
                Console.WriteLine(response.Error.ErrorText);
            } else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("{0} {1} is now signed in",response.FirstName,response.LastName);
                Console.WriteLine("authenticated user id: "+response.UserID);
                user_id = response.UserID;
            }

            GetUserRequestType user_req = new GetUserRequestType();
            user_req.UserID = user_id;
            var user_response = client.GetUser(user_req);

            if (user_response.Error != null)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Error Code: "+user_response.Error.ErrorCode);
                Console.WriteLine("Error Text: "+user_response.Error.ErrorText);
            } else
            {
                Console.WriteLine(user_response.User.Email);
                Console.WriteLine(user_response.User.FirstName);
                Console.WriteLine(user_response.User.LastName);
                Console.WriteLine(user_response.User.Email);
            }

            client.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

and this is my App.config file for the program which seemed to be automatically generated when I added the service reference

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
    <startup> 
        <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.7.2" />
    </startup>
    <system.serviceModel>
        <bindings>
            <basicHttpBinding>
                <binding name="BasicHttpBinding_IEfmUserService" messageEncoding="Mtom">
                    <security mode="TransportWithMessageCredential">
                        <message clientCredentialType="Certificate" />
                    </security>
                </binding>
                <binding name="BasicHttpBinding_IEfmUserService1" messageEncoding="Mtom">
                    <security mode="Transport" />
                </binding>
            </basicHttpBinding>
        </bindings>
        <client>
            <endpoint address="in place of actual address"
                binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="BasicHttpBinding_IEfmUserService"
                contract="EfmUserService.IEfmUserService" name="BasicHttpBinding_IEfmUserService" />
        </client>
    </system.serviceModel>
</configuration>
```

Comment: What technologies are you using? WCF? ASP.NET Core? Web API?

Comment: Also, if you're getting an error, please add it to your question (copy/paste the whole thing, preferably with a stack trace)

Comment: @MartinCostello I am using .NET Framework 4.7.2, I added a service reference on my project to a web API.

Comment: @Gus I'm not getting any actual program error when I run it, but the request gets a response saying "Authentication failed, invalid/expired authentication token or email/password combination". I know the certificate I am using isn't invalid or expired, and after talking with the company that owns the API they told me I was missing a UserName header in the soap request that is made but they couldn't offer any more development assistance than that.

Comment: @MartinCostello I added my code and my app.config file to the post if that would help at all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In time I solved this by adding a `ServiceBehavior` to my `app.config` file. Note that in my case it's a WPF application.

```
<configuration>
  <system.serviceModel>
    <extensions>
      <behaviorExtensions>
        <!-- Add this -->
        <add name="basicAuthenticationBehavior" type="ProjectNamespace.Behaviors.BasicAuthenticationBehaviorExtensionElement, ProjectAssemblyName, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null" />
      </behaviorExtensions>
    </extensions>
    <behaviors>
      <!-- Add this -->
      <endpointBehaviors>
        <behavior name="basicAuthenticationEndpointBehavior">
          <basicAuthenticationBehavior />
        </behavior>
      </endpointBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <bindings>
      <basicHttpBinding>
        <!-- After adding your service reference, your bindings appear here -->
        <binding name="DMSinterfaceSoap">
          <security mode="Transport" />
        </binding>
      </basicHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <client>
      <!-- After adding your service reference, your endpoints appear here -->
      <endpoint address="https://soa.example.com/dmsinterface/DMS_service.asmx" binding="basicHttpBinding" behaviorConfiguration="basicAuthenticationEndpointBehavior" ... />
    </client>
  </system.serviceModel>
<configuration>
```

The `BasicAuthenticationBehaviorExtensionElement` looks like this

```
// Add System.Configuration reference to your ExecutingAssembly
internal class BasicAuthenticationBehaviorExtensionElement : BehaviorExtensionElement
{
    /// <summary>Set this property if you want to send specific headers along with each request</summary>
    public static TCredentials Credentials { internal get; set; }

    public override Type BehaviorType
    {
        get { return typeof(BasicAuthenticationEndpointBehavior); }
    }

    protected override object CreateBehavior()
    {
        return new BasicAuthenticationEndpointBehavior();
    }
}

class BasicAuthenticationEndpointBehavior : IEndpointBehavior
{
    public BasicAuthenticationEndpointBehavior()
    {
    }

    public void Validate(ServiceEndpoint endpoint) { }

    public void AddBindingParameters(ServiceEndpoint endpoint, BindingParameterCollection bindingParameters) { }

    public void ApplyDispatchBehavior(ServiceEndpoint endpoint, EndpointDispatcher endpointDispatcher) { }

    public void ApplyClientBehavior(ServiceEndpoint endpoint, ClientRuntime clientRuntime)
    {
        clientRuntime.MessageInspectors.Add(new BasicAuthenticationClientMessageInspector());
    }
}

class BasicAuthenticationClientMessageInspector : IClientMessageInspector
{
    public object BeforeSendRequest(ref Message request, IClientChannel channel)
    {
        if (BasicAuthenticationBehaviorExtensionElement.Credentials != null)
        {
            SetRequestHeader(ref request, "USERID", BasicAuthenticationBehaviorExtensionElement.Credentials.Credential.UserName);
            SetRequestHeader(ref request, "PSWD", BasicAuthenticationBehaviorExtensionElement.Credentials.Credential.Password);
        }
        return null;
    }

    private void SetRequestHeader(ref Message request, string key, string value)
    {
        object httpRequestMessageObject;
        if (request.Properties.TryGetValue(HttpRequestMessageProperty.Name, out httpRequestMessageObject))
        {
            var httpRequestMessage = httpRequestMessageObject as HttpRequestMessageProperty;
            if (httpRequestMessage != null)
            {
                httpRequestMessage.Headers[key] = (value ?? string.Empty);
            }
            else
            {
                httpRequestMessage = new HttpRequestMessageProperty();
                httpRequestMessage.Headers.Add(key, (value ?? string.Empty));
                request.Properties[HttpRequestMessageProperty.Name] = httpRequestMessage;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            var httpRequestMessage = new HttpRequestMessageProperty();
            httpRequestMessage.Headers.Add(key, (value ?? string.Empty));
            request.Properties.Add(HttpRequestMessageProperty.Name, httpRequestMessage);
        }
    }

    public void AfterReceiveReply(ref Message reply, object correlationState) { }
}
```

This adds the authentication header to each request, based on the object stored in static variable.

Then you can send the soap call with the authentication certificate:

```
#region Get Certificate
var store = new X509Store(StoreName.My, StoreLocation.CurrentUser);
store.Open(OpenFlags.ReadOnly | OpenFlags.OpenExistingOnly);
var foundCerts = store.Certificates.Find(X509FindType.FindBySerialNumber, credential.CertificateSerial, false);

 if (foundCerts.Count == 0)
    throw new Exceptions.NoValidCertificateException();
#endregion
#region Setup client
// Check the App.config for available endpoint configuration names
var client = new MySoapService.DMSinterfaceSoapClient("DMSinterfaceSoap.0");

if (client.Endpoint.Binding is System.ServiceModel.BasicHttpBinding basicBinding)
{
    // DMSinterfaceSoap and DMSinterfaceSoap.0 are BasicHttpBindings
    // The ClientCredentialType is by default set to None. You should be able to combine HttpClientCredentialTypes but sadly that's not possible.
    basicBinding.Security.Transport.ClientCredentialType = System.ServiceModel.HttpClientCredentialType.Certificate;
}
else if (client.Endpoint.Binding is System.ServiceModel.Channels.CustomBinding customBinding)
{
    // DMSinterfaceSoap12 and DMSinterfaceSoap12.0 are CustomBindings
    // Whatever additional configuration needs to be performed
}
#endregion

// Set the USERID and PSWD header
BasicAuthenticationBehaviorExtensionElement.Credentials.Credential = credential;
// Send certificate along with request
client.ClientCredentials.ClientCertificate.Certificate = foundCerts[0];

var error = client.GetResult(req, out res);

// Clear the USERID and PSWD header
 BasicAuthenticationBehaviorExtensionElement.Credentials.Credential = null;
```

Comment: Thanks for coming back to post your solution. WCF configuration can be pretty opaque.

Comment: I know but this was the only way I found to send both an authentication header+certificate

Comment: @Pieterjan I'm trying to test this in my program, but I can't get the program to find the TCredentials class for the static variable.

Comment: It's just some class I made to pass the `CertificateSerial` and the basic-auth username and password to the method. It doesn't exist anywhere. Create it yourself and give it a meaningful name, or pass 3 strings to the method seperately.

Comment: @Pieterjan I think that I adapted it to my program correctly, but when I run it I get an error saying "System.ArgumentException: The provided URI scheme 'https' is invalid; expected 'http'", I'm unsure why I would get this error since your example uses an https endpoint as well.

Comment: The endpoint address shouldn't be copied. You've added the service reference, this inserted the `<endpoint>` tag in your app.config. Don't change it. If the service you're using doesn't accept ssl, you can't use `https`. The `example.com` is something I just made up here.

Comment: @Pieterjan I didn't copy the address in your example. I'm saying I got that error with my address, which is https so it would use ssl right?

Comment: Have you tried with http already?

Comment: @Pieterjan Sorry, after working on this more I realized an ambiguity in my question. I am trying to add a UserName header into the SOAP message headers, not the http request headers.

Comment: @Pieterjan after working on this more and making a few changes to your suggestion to fit my program better, your solution worked for me. Thank you so much, I was stuck on this for weeks.